# TensorFlow installation error: Operation not permitted .../_markerlib

Tags: tensorflow

Despite using `sudo`, the `pip install` command sometimes generates an error similar to the following:

```
...
Installing collected packages: setuptools, protobuf, wheel, numpy, tensorflow
Found existing installation: setuptools 1.1.6
Uninstalling setuptools-1.1.6:
Exception:
…
[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 
'/tmp/pip-a1DXRT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install using `--ignore-installed` option:

```
sudo pip install --ignore-installed tensorflow
```

It should work.